# Backend modal toolbar button that gets activated when list item selected

Tags: extensions, custom-component

Creating a Toolbarbutton which needs a selected list item for dropdown:

```
$childBar->standardButton('delete')->icon('icon-arrow-right')->text('delete')->task('delete')->listCheck(true);
```

or a simple button:

```
$bar = Toolbar::getInstance('toolbar');
$bar->appendButton('Standard', 'delete', 'delete', 'remove', true);
```

Is there a way to do the same for a modal button like this, that also only get activated with a selected list item, so it also gets the `list-selection` class?.

```
ToolbarHelper::modal('myModal', 'icon-pie', 'myModal');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use popup button:

```
$bar->popupButton('modalButton', 'myModal')
    ->icon('icon-pie')
    ->selector('myModal')
    ->listCheck(true);
```

Comment: Thanks. Was searching for the `modalButton`.